# Allow specific IPs to access sub URLs in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

In HAPRoxy I need to block all URLs except for two IP addresses for a specific sub-domain. For Example:
My base URL is www.example.com. And I need to allow only 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 to access the www.example.com/xyz/abc in HAProxy.

Answer (score 1):

you can create 2 different acl and put them in a condition :

```
acl trusted_ip src 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 acl protected_page url www.example.com/xyz/abc
http_request deny if protected_page and not trusted_ip
```

source: https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/acls.html

Comment: acl network_allowed src         1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
acl restricted_pages path_beg   /xyz/abc
http-request deny if restricted_pages and not network_allowed not working. It is blocking for all

Comment: I corrected the entry since the lines had been broke wrong.